# How do you access get parameters in racket server application

Tags: get, scheme, racket

I have a project in my Organization of Programming Languages course and am building a web API using Racket. I have managed to get a server up and running that has multiple landing pages such as

```
localhost:8080/api/add 
localhost:8080/api/subtract
```

I am new to Racket and have just used PHP in the past to handle GET parameter passing via the URL.

such as...

```
localhost:8080/api/add/?num1=1&num2=3
```

`num1` would be accessed by PHP with

```
$_GET[ 'num1' ] ;
```

How should this be done in Racket? I have not found anything in the Racket documentation that shows an equivalent method. My final intent is to pass JSON strings as the GET parameter JSON

```
localhost:8080/api/add/?json={ some json }
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096313/post-get-bindings-in-racket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the solution in

[POST/GET bindings in Racket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096313/post-get-bindings-in-racket)

essentially to get

```
localhost:8080/api/add/?json={ some json }
```

you would use

```
(bytes->string/utf-8 
    (binding:form-value 
        (bindings-assq (string->bytes/utf-8 "[field_name_here]") 
                       (request-bindings/raw req))))
```

Now this answers my question but lets me run into exceptions when the binding searched for is not present, so I decided to take it an extra step and perform an existence check. In PHP I want to perform something like...

```
<?php 

    function get_param_as_string( $param ) {
        if ( isset( $_GET[ $param ] ) )
            return $_GET[ $param ] ;
        return "" ;
    }

?>
```

So I created the racket procedure

```
(define (get-param->string req param)
    (if (eq? #f (bindings-assq (string->bytes/utf-8 param)
                               (request-bindings/raw req)))
        ""
        (bytes->string/utf-8 
           (binding:form-value 
               (bindings-assq (string->bytes/utf-8 param)
                              (request-bindings/raw req))))))
```

Now as in the case specified by the question of the url

```
localhost:8080/api/add/?json={ some json }
```

The following would retrieve the json GET variable if present or would return "" if missing. so...

```
(get-param->string req "json")
```

would result in...

```
{ some json }
```

and

```
localhost:8080/api/add/?tmp={ some json }
```

or

```
localhost:8080/api/add/
```

would result in...

```
""
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are using [Web Application in Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server/).

Servlet procedure recieves request object and it contains those bindings. You can retrieve it by `request-bindings` procedure which returns alist of bindings. The section [4 HTTP: Hypertext Transfer Protocol](http://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server/http.html) describes how to access the request object.

Comment: An example of how your method should be applied would have been helpful.